# jquery: ssl post doesn't call handler data function

Tags: jquery, post

Please consider the following ajax post code

```
$.post('https://'+window.location.host+'/cart/test_payment', $('.submit_order').serialize(), function(data){
    alert('test')
})
```

server side script `test_payment` work out correctly but I do not get alert `test` at the end. If I change protocol to `http` I get alert so now handler function has been called. What is wrong?

Comment: the server certificate is valid?

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to post to that url? What error do you get? And what is the script?

Comment: @putvande yes, I could see results in db. So call has been made. I also checked http headers, I see 200 ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make call from http://, then you will not be able to send AJAX request to https:// destination, and vice-versa. When you try this, it's seen as a different protocol, and in violating of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), so you'll be prevented from seeing the response.